# React router v. 5.3.0: route component doesn't display

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

There are three route components. Navbar is always visible and it works fine. The main page, Home, works too and I can click the link to Checkout, but on the Checkout page I can't see any text, images, or anything except the blank background (as well as the Navbar). When I try to wrap the gradient background div around Checkout, it also doesn't work. Renaming the path of Checkout doesn't help as well.

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './navbar'
import Home from './Home'
import Checkout from "./Checkout"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <div className="gradient__bg">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          </div>
          <Route path='checkout' component={Checkout}>
            <Checkout />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `Switch` only renders the ***first*** matched `Route` or `Redirect` component, but you've wrapped one of the `Route` components in a `div` element which breaks this abstraction and will always be rendered, so if there are routes *after* the div they won't ever be able to be matched and rendered. This means the checkout route/path is never rendered.

To resolve, move the wrapper `div` inside the `Route` component.

Also, don't specify the `component` prop ***and*** provide children components. You can either wrap the child component

```
<Route path='/'>
  <div className="gradient__bg">
    <Home />
  </div>
</Route>
```

or use the `render` prop and forward the route props to the `Home` component

```
<Route
  path='/'
  render={props => (
    <div className="gradient__bg">
      <Home {...props} />
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

Note: Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matter, you should order the routes from more specific paths to less specific paths. Don't forget that the `Checkout` component's path should include the leading `"/"`, i.e. it should be `"/checkout"`.

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/checkout'>
        <Checkout />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/'>
        <div className="gradient__bg">
          <Home />
        </div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make checkout route above the home route

```
   <Route path='checkout' component={Checkout}>
        <Checkout />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
        <Home />
      </Route>
```